# Frame whole sections in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, context, framed

I am trying to improve overview in working sheets and right now I am trying to frame a whole section, preferably with rounded corners but couldn't find any solutions. Is there something like `\framedsection` in context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `textbackground` environment to put a frame around the content of a section. With the `beforesection` and `aftersection` keys you can start and stop the frame at the begin and end of a section but you have to use start/stop-version of a section command to get this working.

Unlike other mechanism like the `background` environment `textbackground` doesn’t change the position of the section content and works also with floats and split tables.

```
\definetextbackground
  [SectionFrame]
  [background=,
   framecolor=red,
   corner=round,
   location=paragraph,
   before={\blank[2*big]}]

\definehead[framedsection][section]

\setuphead
  [framedsection]
  [before=,
   beforesection={\starttextbackground[SectionFrame]},
   aftersection=\stoptextbackground]

\starttext

\startsection[title=Knuth]
\input knuth
\stopsection

\startframedsection[title=Tufte]
\input tufte
\stopframedsection

\stoptext
```

[image: Adding a frame around the content of a section]

To improve the layout of the frame you can create your own `MetaPost` graphic which add a distance between the frame and the content.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{sectionframe}
    begingroup;
        for i=1 upto nofmultipars :
            draw ( llcorner multipars[i]
                -- lrcorner multipars[i]
                -- urcorner multipars[i]
                -- ulcorner multipars[i]
                -- cycle )
            enlarged (EmWidth,EmWidth)
            cornered (2*EmWidth)
            withcolor "red" ;
        endfor ;
    endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definetextbackground
  [SectionFrame]
  [mp=sectionframe,
   location=paragraph,
   before={\blank[2*big]}]
```

[image: Custom design for the section frame]

Answer (score 7):

Use the `background` mechanism.  It can break across pages.

```
\unprotect

\definebackground
  [_background_framed_section]
  [
    corner=round,
    frame=on,
    background=,
  ]

\define\startframedsection{\dodoubleempty\start_framed_section}
\define\stopframedsection{\stop_framed_section}

\starttexdefinition unexpanded start_framed_section [#1][#2]
  \start_background_framed_section
  \doifsomethingelse{#2}{
    \message{first branch}
    \getvalue{start#1}[#2]
    \setvalue{stop_framed_section_level}{#1}
  }{
    \message{second branch}
    \startsection[#1]
    \setvalue{stop_framed_section_level}{section}
  }
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition unexpanded stop_framed_section
  \getvalue{stop\getvalue{stop_framed_section_level}}
  \stop_background_framed_section
\stoptexdefinition

\protect

\starttext

\startframedsection[title=Knuth]
  \dorecurse{10}{
    \input knuth
  }
\stopframedsection

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: The `background` environment has limitations when the section contains floats or split tables with repeated headers/footers.