# ConTeXt: Missing Chapter Numbers

Tags: numbering, chapters, context

## Code

Minimum working example (MWE):

```
\setuphead[chapter][number=yes,]
\setuphead[section][number=no,]
\setuphead[subsection][placehead=hidden,]

\definehead[scenesubsection][subsection]

\starttext
  \dorecurse{5}{
    \chapter{Chapter Name}
    \section{Section Name}
    \startscenesubsection
    \input tufte
    \stopscenesubsection
  }
\stoptext
```

## Problem

The chapter headings should be enumerated 1 through 5, but some chapter numbers are either hidden or enumerated incorrectly.

The following figure shows the MWE output:

[image: Example Output]

## Question

How can the problems with chapter numbering be resolved?

## Additional Details

```
$ context --version
mtx-context     | current version: 2017.05.14 19:09
```

## Work Around

Using `placehead=no` causes the spacing to change when [framing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369721/context-frame-entire-section-of-pandoc-generated-document) an entire section:

[image: Placehead No]

Comment: I get the same weird behaviour, and don't understand it. I wonder though, do you really need `\startscenesubsection ... \stopscenesubsection`—with `placehead=hidden` the `scenesubsection` headers might as well *not* be there, and removing them seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you use `placehead=no` instead of `hidden`?

Comment: Seems to be not yet fully implemented.  There is a [todo in the code](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/b14f992ef5f4e868c9959b174278c86516d60dbc/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-sec.mkiv#L930).

Comment: `\startscenesubsection\getheadsyncs` works for me on TL2016.  I was not yet able to track it down though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom counter:

```
\definecounter[ChapterNumber][
  way=bytext,
  prefix=no,
]

\define[1]\CustomChapter{%
  \incrementcounter[ChapterNumber] 
  \rawcountervalue[ChapterNumber] 
  \hspace[medium]
  #1
} 

\setuphead[chapter][
  align=middle,
  number=no,
  textcommand=\CustomChapter,
]

\setuphead[section][
  align=middle,
  number=no,
]

\setuphead[subsection][
  placehead=hidden,
  number=no,
]

\definehead[scenesubsection][subsection]
```