# Context Box Similar to tcolorbox

Tags: context, tcolorbox

This is a question that is similar to [this one.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/486078/is-there-any-alternative-for-tcolorbox-in-context) I wished to implement two features of `tcolorbox`:

- Box titles, with their respective list with `placelistofXXX`
- Ability to choose between rounded and straight box edges.

What I had in mind was basically joining both frames below, but I still can't figure out spacing and overlay.

```
\starttext
\startframedtext[background=color,backgroundcolor=orange,width=.8\textwidth,align=flushleft,frame=off,bottomframe=on,framecolor=blue,bottomframe=on,rulethickness=2pt,width=.8\textwidth,location=middle,loffset=-1ex,toffset=-1ex,boffset=-1ex]
\bf A grandiose and reverential title, praising the stones and trees
\stopframedtext

\startframedtext[frame=off,topframe=on,bottomframe=on,framecolor=darkgray,background=color,backgroundcolor=lightgray,corner=round,width=.8\textwidth,location=middle]
\input tufte
\stopframedtext


\stoptext
```

---

Edit:

Basically what I wanted was a simple `tcolorbox` with title, number, and content in a separate `placecontent`:

[image: a box]

Comment: I think it could help with a picture of what you try to achive. In particular it is difficult to know what spacing you want.

Comment: @mickep, I wanted to put the first frame inside, and aligned with, the second, so that this "frame inside the frame" would be a numbered title. But if I do that there's a left and top space I haven't figured out how to remove yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll simply use natural tables to get the desired output:

```
\usemodule[annotation]

\usecolors[solarized]


\startsetups table:tcolorbox
  \setupTABLE[row][1]
             [
               background=color,
               backgroundcolor=red,
               foregroundcolor=base3,
               foregroundstyle=bold,
               framecolor=red,
               rulethickness=1.5bp,
               corner=03,
               loffset=0.25em,
               roffset=0.25em,
             ]

  \setupTABLE[row][2]
             [
               background=color,
               backgroundcolor=base2,
               foregroundcolor=base03,
               framecolor=red,
               rulethickness=1.5bp,
               corner=01,
               loffset=0.25em,
               roffset=0.25em,
               align={normal,hyphenated},
             ]
\stopsetups

\startsetups annotation:tcolorbox
  \startTABLE[setups=table:tcolorbox]
    \NC \placeannotationtext\space
        \placeannotationnumber:\space
        \placeannotationtitle   \NC \NR
    \NC \placeannotationcontent \NC \NR
  \stopTABLE
  \writetolist[tcolorbox]{\placeannotationnumber}{\placeannotationtitle}
\stopsetups

\defineannotationalternative
    [tcolorbox]
    [
      alternative=vertical,
      renderingsetup=annotation:tcolorbox,
    ]

\defineannotation[tcolorbox]
                 [
                   text=Example,
                   number=yes,
                   alternative=tcolorbox,
                 ]


\starttext

\placelist[tcolorbox][alternative=b,criterium=all, headnumber=always]

\section{One}

\starttcolorbox[title={Title with a number}]
  \input ward
\stoptcolorbox

\starttcolorbox[title={Title with a number}]
  \input ward
\stoptcolorbox


\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]
If you want straight edges, simply comment out the `corner=...` lines.

Comment: It all went well, however, `\placelist[tcolorbox][criterium=all]` seems to have no effect.

Comment: @BlackBird: I edited the answer so that placelist works.

Comment: Aditya, much appreciated!