# Shadowbox with ConTeXt

Tags: context

How to get the same result of `\shadowbox` in LaTeX with ConTeXt ?

```
%\usepackage{fancybox}
\shadowbox{text}
```

[image]

This is my atttempt to use Metapost, this my MWE :

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usecolors[crayola]
\startuniqueMPgraphic{cadre}
 path q; q := (0.5,-1) -- (OverlayWidth+0.5,-1) -- (OverlayWidth+0.5, OverlayHeight) -- (0.5, OverlayHeight) --   (0.5,-1) -- cycle;
 path p; p := (0,0) -- (OverlayWidth,0) -- (OverlayWidth, OverlayHeight) -- (0, OverlayHeight) --   (0,0);
  fill q withpen pencircle scaled 5pt withcolor \MPcolor{black} ;
  fill p withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor gray ;
 setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox OverlayBox;
 \stopuniqueMPgraphic
\defineoverlay[cadre][\useMPgraphic{cadre}]
 \defineframedtext[shadowbox][frame=off,background=cadre,width=\makeupwidth]

 \starttext
  
 \startshadowbox
  \input knuth
  \stopshadowbox

  \stoptext
```

Comment: Could you show what you are willing to do? Some ConTeXt users don't have LaTeX installed. Btw, you *are* using metapost: `uniqueMPgraphic` is a metafun command. EDIT: an example of shadowbox here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185051/customise-bullet-points-inside-shadowbox

Comment: The link show exactly what I want.This my attempt to use Metapost, I do not know if it is correct !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether or not it counts as a duplicate, but I'll post an answer if helpful. For an example of how defining your own MetaPost backgrounds, you could look at [this answer by Wolfgang Schuster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348699/226564). Options for text background alternatives are, e.g., `always` (applied to the whole text), `paragraph` and `text` (applies to words).

In the MetaPost side, `boundingbox` is a macro to draw, as you might imagine, the bounding box of each page/paragraph/line and `nofmultipars` is just the number of units to handle. In our case, `always` only breaks across pages.

```
%\setuppapersize[A6]
\startuseMPgraphic{shadowed}
begingroup;
    path MyFrame, MyShadow;
    numeric MyThickness; MyThickness := 4bp;
    for i=1 upto nofmultipars:
        MyFrame := boundingbox multipars[i] enlarged (EmWidth,EmWidth);
        MyShadow := MyFrame shifted (1/2MyThickness*(1,-1));
        draw MyFrame;
        draw (
            (MyThickness*right + llcorner MyShadow)
            --lrcorner MyShadow
            --(MyThickness*down + urcorner MyShadow)
            )
        withpen pensquare scaled MyThickness;
    endfor 
endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definetextbackground
  [shadowed]
  [mp=shadowed,
   location=always]

\starttext
\startshadowed
\input knuth
\stopshadowed
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jairo A. del Rio, that's exactly what I want !